# SASL not blocking non authenticated user sending email to itself

Tags: postfix, sasl

My email server is working fine except that still allows anyone to send email from a my@email.pt to my@email.pt. 
I eanbled in /etc/postfix/main.cf

```
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated,permit_mynetworks,reject_unauth_destination,...
```

And in /etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-master.conf

```
service auth {
    unix_listener auth-userdb {
    mode = 0600
    user = mail
    #group =
}
```

And i restart the postfix. But still is possible to send emails to itselft without authentication. Can anyone tell me what am i missing? Thank you.